# My Ruby on Rails active record validation error does not persist when I re-render the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, error-handling, carrierwave

I'm using Rails 7 and Carrierwave to upload images.

My image uploading is working as expected, but my issue is happening when I try to implement validation error message for an incorrect file type. In my app/uploaders/user_avatar_uploader.rb file I specify to only accept jpeg, jpg and png files.

When I use the following code and test with binding.pry (after trying to update my form), I can see that there is 1 error on the @user_profile object.

```
def edit
        @user_profile = UserProfile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @user_profile = UserProfile.find(params[:id])
        if @user_profile.update(user_profile_params)
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            binding.pry
        end
    end
```

However, when I revise the update method with the code below and I try and see the errors in my edit view, nothing shows up. To be clear, I'm trying to re-render the same view (edit) that was originally showing, and show the errors.

```
def update
        @user_profile = UserProfile.find(params[:id])
        if @user_profile.update(user_profile_params)
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
```

Here is the code I've included in my my edit view to try and show the errors. I'm getting '0' for the count and it's not showing any error messages after submitting the form with an invalid file type for the carrierwave upload.

```
<%= @user_profile.errors.count %>

    <% if @user_profile.errors.any? %>
      <h3>Some errors were found:</h3>
      <ul>
        <% @user_profile.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
```

Any idea what could be happening? I know the errors are there when my update controller action fires, but for some reason they're not being carried over to the render of my 'edit' view.

**EDIT**

I added the binding.pry directly in my view, after the code where I'm checking if there are any errors in the view. In the view, I'm not seeing any errors. But in the binding.pry in the console when I check `@user_profile.errors.any?` I get `true` and can see the error.

```
<h3>Profile</h3>

<%= @user_profile.errors.count %>

<% if @user_profile.errors.any? %>
  <h3>Some errors were found:</h3>
  <ul>
    <% @user_profile.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<% binding.pry %>
```

Comment: This question is going to be impossible to answer from the outside. We just don't have a complete enough picture to be able to isolate the bug. You need to continue on your debugging journey and ensure that you're not for example reassigning `@user_profile` somewhere before it gets to the view.

Comment: @max I agree with you, but where could I possibly be reassigning `@user_profile` in between the update action of the same controller and rendering the "edit" view? There shouldn't be anything in between those two steps right?

Comment: Weird that when you add the `binding.pry` you took out the `render 'edit'`. Possible that you're doing something in that session that's affecting the errors. Change that and if your pry session shows errors but your view doesn't, then there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: @smathy Thanks for your help. Check my edit above. I even added the binding.pry directly in the view and I'm getting the same result. binding.pry shows the error, but the view itself does not. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @smathy and to more directly address your suggestion above, when I add `binding.pry` below the `render: edit` I do still see the error in my pry session and I do not see the errors in the view.

Comment: Put it before, so any side effets of the pry session will affect the view rendering too. May as well show us the pry session too, just in case you're doing something weird in there.

Comment: @smathy same result with it before. I just posted the answer. Turns out it was related to turbo needing to be disabled in Rails 7. Usually in Rails I've discovered that whenever something doesn't make sense and you've exhausted all possibilities, it's usually turbolinks or something biting you. The worst part is there was no documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: Sorry about that, I totally missed you mentioning this was a turbo form/request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to disable turbo to get this to work properly. I also rewrote my `form_for` to a `form_with` since the former is being deprecated.

New code:

```
<%= form_with(model: @user_profile, data: { turbo: false }) do |f| %>
```